# Tests run slower after migration ALM 11.52 to 12.21

Tags: performance, qtp, alm

I have tests in my scope which are running more than 10 minutes. After migration to 12.21 ALM these tests freezes for more than 15-30 minutes during execution and final time execution of such tests more than 30 minutes. But 50% of tests I stopped because their execution reach more than 1 hour. The most interesting, that test which I have already reviewed stacked on step when I'm extracting data from database to Excel - for example 3000 seconds for 100 entries.

NB: fast tests (300 seconds) now running nearly the 320 seconds.

Is it possible to fix this performance issue? What could be a reason of such problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a db performance issue when you are extracting data to Excel. You could verify how long the relevant queries take when they are being executed against database directly. Are there any query optimization needed?  index corruption/missing (rebuild indexes if so)? or high water mark issue (Oracle only, if so, purge the table and then import the backup data)? or any deadlock in database?

If none of above, you could collect the Server logs(debug level), WebGate logs and UFT/QTP logs which will be helpful to narrow the bottleneck at high level according to the time consumed by each step. Then you could drill down the specific scenario.

Thanks,
Allen